# Using apply: Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, apply

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(1:4), B = c(10:13), C = c(19:22))
```

I would like to calculate 1/A + 1/C row wise

```
df$calc <- apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(1/x[,c(1,3)])

Error in x[, c(1, 3)] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I dont see why I should get a error here when

```
fun<- function(x){

 f <- sum(1/x[,c(1,3)])
 return(f)
}

fun(data[1,])
1.052632
```

Works without problems

Comment: Did you meant `apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(1/x[c(1,3)]))`

Comment: Or is it `1/data[["A"]] + 1/data[["C"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `rowSums` as it is vectorized

```
data$calc <- rowSums(1/data[c("A", "C")])
```

Or another efficient option is

```
Reduce(`+`, 1/data[c("A", "C")])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe

`df <- apply(data, 1, function(x) sum(1/x[c(1,3)]))`

is what you want